# MySQL - sums are getting multiplied

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I'm trying to get data from `table_a`, and a `sum()` from a left joined `table_b`, an another `sum()` from another left joined `table_c`

So, joining `a` with `b`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, sum(b.quantity)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b on b.id_table_a = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Outputs

| id | name | sum(b.quantity) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 14 |

And, joining `a` with `c`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, sum(c.quantity)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_c c on c.id_table_a = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Outputs

| id | name | sum(c.quantity) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 8 |

My problem occurs when I try to join `a` with `b` and `c` at the same time

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM(b.quantity), SUM(c.quantity)
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id_table_a = a.id
LEFT JOIN table_c c ON c.id_table_a = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Outputs

| id | name | sum(b.quantity) | sum(c.quantity) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 28 | 24 |

The `sum()`'s are getting multiplied by the number of rows from the joined tables (14x2 and 8x3)

**At this point the question is: How can I get the correct sums?**

This is what I expect:

| id | name | sum(b.quantity) | sum(c.quantity) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 14 | 8 |

Right now I'm doing the following, but I would like to know if the same result can be achieved using the previous query, maybe I'm missing something in the group by?

```
SELECT 
    x.*, SUM(c.quantity)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        a.id, a.name, SUM(b.quantity)
    FROM
        table_a a
    LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.id_table_a = a.id
    GROUP BY a.id) x
        LEFT JOIN
    table_c c ON c.id_table_a = x.id
GROUP BY x.id;
```

Here is a link to a fiddle and below the SQL

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40639

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_table_a` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_table_b_id_table_a1_idx` (`id_table_a` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table_b_id_table_a1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_table_a`)
    REFERENCES `table_a` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE `table_c` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_table_a` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_table_c_id_table_a1_idx` (`id_table_a` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table_c_id_table_a1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_table_a`)
    REFERENCES `table_a` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO `table_a` (`name`) VALUES ('test');
INSERT INTO `table_b` (`id_table_a`, `quantity`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `table_b` (`id_table_a`, `quantity`) VALUES ('1', '4');
INSERT INTO `table_b` (`id_table_a`, `quantity`) VALUES ('1', '8');
INSERT INTO `table_c` (`id_table_a`, `quantity`) VALUES ('1', '3');
INSERT INTO `table_c` (`id_table_a`, `quantity`) VALUES ('1', '5');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common "join multiplying". Possible solution - aggregate over single table in subquery (for each aggregated table) then join.

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.name, sum_b, sum_c
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_table_a, SUM(quantity) sum_b
            FROM table_b
            GROUP BY id_table_a ) b ON b.id_table_a = a.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_table_a, SUM(quantity) sum_c
            FROM table_c
            GROUP BY id_table_a ) c ON c.id_table_a = a.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=32c4b2898693a21e799a84970a87b3c8

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the best performance is:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 
       (SELECT SUM(b.quantity) 
        FROM table_b b
        WHERE b.id_table_a = a.id
       ) as sum_b,
       (SELECT SUM(c.quantity) 
        FROM table_c c
        WHERE c.id_table_a = a.id
       ) as sum_c
FROM table_a a;
```

For performance you want indexes on `table_b(id_table_a, quantity)` and `table_c(id_table_a, quantity)`.